# When I take screenshot of UIView, why do I get a transparent strip on and how to determine the strip height programatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

I make a simple program to take screenshot

The purpose is for a trick of displaying a not so full screen modal. Take screenshot of the presentingViewController and then display that on background.

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>

@implementation UIView (screenshot)
- (UIImage*) screenshot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return myImage;
}

@end
```

Simple enough.

Now I do:
[BGMDCachedProperties singleton].screenShotOfLastPresentingController = self.navigationController.view.screenshot;//Take the screen shot, put it in a variable

Then I do
    [[BGMDCachedProperties singleton].screenShotOfLastPresentingController saveScreenshot];

```
-(void)saveScreenshot{
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self);
    NSString * documentDirectory= [BGMDApplicationsPointers applicationDocumentsDirectory];
    NSString * fileForDocumentDirectory = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",@"foo.png"];
    BOOL result = [data writeToFile:fileForDocumentDirectory atomically:YES];
    if (result)
    {

    }
}
```

This is what I got:
[image]

Then I display a mock viewController whose purpose is to display that image. Maybe I just misinterpret that foo.png right? I set the background to red so we know

This is what I got:
[image]

Obviously that doesn't work for my purpose because I will need to do this:

[image]

Finally I managed to get it fixed by just getting rid the top 20 points of the screenshot.

```
theScreenshot = theScreenshot.crop20PointsifStatusBarShowsUp;

-(UIImage*) crop20PointsifStatusBarShowsUp
{
    if ([BGMDApplicationsPointers statusBarShowUp])
    {
        CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(0, sizeOfStatusBar, self.size.width, self.size.height-sizeOfStatusBar);
        UIImage * newImage = [self cropUIImageWithCGRect:newSize];
        return newImage;
    }
    else{
        return [self copy];
    }
}
```

I finally got it work:
[image]
However, if a user allow personal hotspot, their status bar would be 40 points instead.

I wonder why the transparent strip shows up at navigationController.view given that like all view, navigation controller is only supposed to fill the screen that's "available" rather than the whole screen.

Also how do I know the size of the strip? Sometimes it's 0 when there is not status bar, sometimes it's 20, and sometimes it's 40.

I added these 2 codes:

```
PO(NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
PO(NSStringFromCGSize(myImage.size));
```

and got:

```
2012-10-12 07:57:34.627 BadgerNew[3354:907] <0x1cdc8a60 UIView+screenshot.m:(21)> NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame): {{0, 0}, {320, 431}}
2012-10-12 07:57:34.629 BadgerNew[3354:907] <0x1cdc8a60 UIView+screenshot.m:(22)> NSStringFromCGSize(myImage.size): {320, 431}
```

Comment: What's the value of myImage.frame ?

Comment: PO(NSStringFromCGRect(myImage.frame)); /business/Dropbox/badgers/BadgerNew/UIView+screenshot.m:22:5: Property 'frame' not found on object of type 'UIImage *'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not understand why I get the strip. It seems that navigationController.view always fill the whole screen and then have a transparent screen so not to cover the status bar.

modalViewController, for example, live the status bar alone.

So the only good solution is to just compute the size of status bar and crop the image.

```
-(UIImage*) crop20PointsifStatusBarShowsUp
{
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    float sizeOfStatusBarVar= applicationFrame.origin.y;
    if ([BGMDApplicationsPointers statusBarShowUp])
    {
        CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(0, sizeOfStatusBarVar, self.size.width, self.size.height-sizeOfStatusBarVar);
        UIImage * newImage = [self cropUIImageWithCGRect:newSize];
        return newImage;
    }
    else{
        return [self copy];
    }
}
```

You need to compute that programatically because the size of the status bar is often 40 if you have private hot spot.